# I guess i need dynamic variables in javascript to do this?

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic

I am trying to use this stopwatch here: [Stopwatch Script](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/stopwatch.php) but for many counters on the page, that are dynamically created via php loops.
For example:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" id="bn1" data-bid="n1">Start</button>
<br><br>
<div id=n1></div>
<br><br>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="bn2" data-bid="n2">Start</button>
<br><br>
<div id=n2></div>
```

Using jquery i am trying to create 2 simple functions. One to start each timer clicked and one to stop it

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script language=javascript>
var vars = {};
var bid;
var h = 0;
var m = 0;
var s = 0;

$('[class^=btn]').on('click', function() {
  var pause = $(this).text() === 'Stop';
  $(this).text(pause ? 'Start' : 'Stop');
  bid = $(this).attr('data-bid');
  return (this.timvar ^= 1) ? startimer(bid) : stop(bid);
});


function stop(bid) {
  clearTimeout(['tm' + bid]);
}

function startimer(bid) {
  //vars['tm' + bid] = setInterval('disp('+bid+')',1000);
  vars['tm' + bid] = setInterval(function() {
    disp(bid)
  }, 1000);
}

function disp(bid) {
  //alert(bid);
  // Format the output by adding 0 if it is single digit //
  if (s < 10) {
    var s1 = '0' + s;
  } else {
    var s1 = s;
  }
  if (m < 10) {
    var m1 = '0' + m;
  } else {
    var m1 = m;
  }
  if (h < 10) {
    var h1 = '0' + h;
  } else {
    var h1 = h;
  }
  // Display the output //
  str = h1 + ':' + m1 + ':' + s1;
  document.getElementById(bid).innerHTML = str;
  // Calculate the stop watch // 
  if (s < 59) {
    s = s + 1;
  } else {
    s = 0;
    m = m + 1;
    if (m == 60) {
      m = 0;
      h = h + 1;
    } // end if  m ==60
  } // end if else s < 59
  // end of calculation for next display
}
</script>
```

Somehow i have to be able to execute these 2 functions multiple times for each button, that will use a dynamic 'tm' variable that updates the text inside the n1 and n2..(etc) divs with the timer. And then when the user presses stop to be able to stop that specific tm var.
But...i am kinda lost when it comes to dynamic variables and how to properly pass them around between javascript functions...I am not even sure if there is a simpler way of doing this...I dont know what's the proper term to search for it in google. Any advice ? What am i doing wrong ?
-Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID. Use a class instead. `<button type="button" class="btn" data-bid="n1">Start</button>`. Also, look into `setInterval` for repeatedly calling a function.

Comment: I use the same id to be able to execute that js that changes the button's text, i do have unique data-bid for each div. The document.getElementById(bid).innerHTML=str; is wrong i know....but i havent reached that 'place' yet to fix it...since i cant even get the proper bid var inside that function.
I am using setInterval in startimer function...the problem is that tm has to be dynamic (one for each button) and the variable bid doesnt pass to disp() function

Comment: ids have to be unique! Your buttons share the same id, this will break it all from the beginning

Comment: You can do the exact same thing with a class.
ID: `$('#btn').text('Text');`
Class: `$('.btn').text('Text');` Also, what @Michael said is correct, you really need unique ID's. And if you need to change the text of only one button, as in your example, use the ID or your data-bid attr. You can even use `event.target.id` with an onClick instead of the data-bid; `event.target.id` returns the ID of the DOM element that called the function through onClick.

Comment: Ok i changed the code again to reflect the class change...It should be working now, but its not. The startimer function is not passing var bid in disp()

Comment: do this:  `vars['tm' + bid] = setInterval(function(){disp(bid)},1000);`

Comment: Why use the data-bid attr at all? The code would be significantly simplified by just utilizing the unique ID's.

Comment: holy c... That showed the timer :) See what i mean about the syntax? The timer is not starting but i guess thats my fault with the setInterval...

Comment: @Bjonnfesk i was using those before the last code change...i have to remove that part i know. But for now i'll leave it since it gets the ID.